# How to execute multiple testng files sequentially?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Below is the Configuration that I have added to the Pom.xml file to execute the two files

```
<configuration>
  <suiteXmlFiles>
     <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
       <suiteXmlFile>/path/to/xml/Suite1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
       <suiteXmlFile>/path/to/xml/Suite2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
  </suiteXmlFiles>
 <testSourceDirectory>src/main/java</testSourceDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Then executing via maven using ***mvn test***

Comment: Is your testsource directory src/main/java?   Where have you placed your xmls? What surefire version?

Comment: @niharika_neo Yes my test scripts are under Main folder. Sure-fire version is 2.19.1. 
  XML Files are under src/main/resources  folder

Comment: Where have you placed your xmls and what is path to xml?

Comment: src/main/resources/Suite1.xml

Comment: I have the same version and it works for me both suites get executed.  Can you paste the log.  Also I hope you don't have the first slash in the path that you have shown in the question snippet